# Regular expressions and Shell scripts

Tags: regex, shell

I have learning about regular expressions and shell scripts . I have a directory /work/test/ where I have multiple files like the following files:  needstc_30554-r-00051,  profilemd5_30323-r-00053, unchanged_30394-r-00053 .

I want to extract the first number ONLY from files that start with unchanged  like the unchanged_30397-r-30554 file , and the number is this case would be 30397.

I had been playing around with regular expressions and was able to extract the id from one single file with the following:

```
    str='profiles_060315091024_30398-r-00006.avro'
    myvar=$(awk -F'[_-]' '{print $3}' <<< "$str")
```

So my question is:

How could I go in to that directory and get the first number only from files that start with unchanged ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find command to get a list of filenames and then the cut command to pull out the parts you want. A for loop could then be used to iterate over them but that requires that all results fit on a singe shell command line, and if you get too many files in a directory the command fails. A while loop will handle an arbitrary number of files.

```
find /work/test -type f -name 'unchanged*' | \
    cut -d_ -f2 | cut -d- -f1 | \
    while read fname;do echo $fname;done
```

If all you need is the list of values, you can omit the while loop -- it's just there as a placeholder in case you wanted to do something with each value.

The first argument after the find command is the top-level directory; find will recurse into any subdirectories. "-type f" limits its output to regular files. The -name option limits its output to just files beginning with unchanged.

"cut" is a nice utility for pulling out fields between delimiters. The first cut's "-d_" says to use the underscore as a delimiter, and "-f2" says to grab the second field; this gives us everything after the underscore. Next we specify a dash as a delimiter and grab what comes before the first one; this is our number. We're getting a stream of these, one per line, which we pass into the while loop. The read command will read one whitespace-delimited word at a time into the given variable name and let you do whatever you want with it.

The above commands won't deal well with unusual filenames containing newline characters, or extracted terms containing spaces, but it doesn't sound like you have that to deal with here.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is an excellent solution. I like the fact that I do not need to use a for loop or while loop if I do not need it. The other answers were very helpful as well but this one works for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I would use **Grep** from the output of **ls** together with **AWK** (by piping them).

```
ls | grep '^unchanged_' | awk -F'[_-]' '{print $2}'
```

1. **ls**: get file names of the directory
2. **grep**: get matched files only (file name filetering)
3. **awk**: basically this is identical with your original sample (note: the number should be `$2`)

Comment: how could I specify in the ls a directory??

Comment: one last question. What is the purpose of  ^ before the unchanged name

Comment: In regex `^` means the starting point of string. It matches 'unchanged_...' but doesn't match like '(any character+)unchanged_...'. If you are sure that your files don't include the word 'unchanged' in their names other than the starting position of string, it would not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Use a wildcard to select matching files: `unchanged_*`.

Step 2) Extract the numbers. You could use a regex, but an even easier way using purely shell constructs is to remove the stuff before and after the number.

What this looks like:

```
cd /work/test/

for file in unchanged_*; do
    number=${file#unchanged_}   # remove "unchanged_"
    number=${number%%-*}        # remove everything after dash

    echo "$number"
done
```

Comment: Divide and conquer. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#iterate files in current directory matching file spec
for ( glob("./unchanged_*") ) {
    #regular expression match first instance of 'one or more digits' into
    # $number
    if ( my ($number) = m/(\d+)/ ) {
        #print if that regex matched
        print $number, "\n";
    }
}
```

You could one-liner this if you wanted to.

Comment: Why a perl answer to a shell question?

Comment: Because it's also a `regex` question, and it's not like most Unix based systems don't have both available.